# CakePHP: Let the Users choose the Language

Tags: php, cakephp

I want users to choose their language in a cakePHP app. I have default.po files for German and English. But when I call `$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'ger');` in a Controller function, nothing happens.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Controller function:

```
public function changeLang() { 
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    $this->Session->write('Config.language','ger'); 
    Configure::write('Config.language','ger'); 
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Language changed succefully.')); 
    $this->redirect($this->referer()); 
}
```

Comment: What version of cakephp?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.3

Comment: Do you have a before filter in your Language controller? Are you calling parent::beforeFilter(); in it? It's hard to tell if anything is happening even in the config without some kind of notice. Can you try `pr(Configure::read('Config.language'));` to check if any values are actually being set?

Comment: Yes, i have beforeFilter in it and i am calling the parent. It saves the value in my session and config, but it keeps beeing english :/

Comment: **Note**:  You should be using `'de'` (German) or `'de-DE'` (German - Germany dialect) as your language code for German, as that's the ISO-639 standard.

Comment: A quick google search showed a number of results where the language was defined in bootstrap or core and overrides the configure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513862/cakephp-localization-cannot-change-language-when-default-language-is-set

Comment: It does not work with de, de-DE and ger. 
@TimJoyce I dont have any lang-config in my core or bootstrap.

Comment: I noticed that in /app/tmp/cache/persistent/ the file with the _ger ending has no content whereas the file with the _eng ending has content.

Comment: That's because it never reaches the ger content just like we have already narrowed down. Did you check that link? Look for constants defined in your core or bootstrap that are overriding the Config?

Comment: My file is /app/Locale/ger/LC_MESSAGES/default.po and I searched core and config for "language" but I did not get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i used the wrong language-code for my folder. I had "ger" but it should have been "deu".

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html%20here) states that you need to write to the configure class as well as set the session variable.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this in my AppController as well. And in my LangController I implemented:
`public function changeLang() {
  $this->autoRender = false;
  $this->Session->write('Config.language','ger');
  Configure::write('Config.language','ger');
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Language changed succefully.'));
  $this->redirect($this->referer());
}`